# AngularJs routes - scroll doesn't change after I go to another state

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

Simple question. When I scroll down and press any button that goes to a different state ($state.go('other_template')), the second state loads but the scroll continues at the same level where I left it when I pressed the button. Doesn't go to the top.

There's any configuration to change this? How can I make to focus on my navbar for instance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is ngView retains the current scroll position when it loads a new view. The solution is to add autoscroll="true" to your ngView element:

```
<div class="ng-view" autoscroll="true"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I ended up using something like: <div ui-view autoscroll="true">

Answer (score 0):

There is no such configuration.

`ui-router` is responsible for the state change and it does it well.

In a new state or before you call `$state.go(..)` you may use `$window.scrollTo(0, 0);` to scroll to the top or add position of the `navbar` as a second parameter.